# ActionMailer「deliver_later」でメールが送信できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

よろしくお願い致します。

Heroku環境
Rails 5.1.5
gem `delayed_job`/`daemons`/`capistrano`導入済み

ActiveJobを利用して非同期でメール送信を行ないたいと思っています。
開発環境ではletter_openerを使用してメールが届くことをすでに確認済みです。

【現在の状況】
モデルでメール送信用のメソッドを記述

```
def self.notification
  NoticeMailer.notification.deliver_later
end
```

Capfile

```
require 'capistrano/delayed_job'
```

config/deploy.rb

```
set :delayed_job_workers, 1
set :delayed_job_roles, [:app]
```

【問題】
Heroku側でメール送信を試みた際、ログを見る限りジョブをキューに追加するところまではできているのに、送信ができていないと言う状況です。
手動で`heroku run rails jobs:worker`とワーカーを起動すると、メールを送信することができます。
また、メール送信のメソッドを`deliver_later`ではなく`deliver_now`へ変更した場合もメール送信できています。

【自分で試した方法】
Herokuのガイドを参考に、

Procfile

```
worker: rails jobs:work
```

モデル側

```
def self.notification
  NoticeMailer.delay.notification
end
```

へ変更してみましたが、結果変わらず手動でワーカーを立ち上げない限り、メールが届かないと言う状況です。

【懸念点】
「daemonsを導入しているにも関わらず、ワーカーが立ち上がっていない」という点が問題なのではないかと考えています。
関係のありそうなファイルにrequire 'daemons'してみたりなどしてみましたが、効果がなく…

何か良い方法をご存知の方はいらっしゃいませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/119462